# ¿Fijar disposición y tamaño de componentes (RecyclerView)?

Tags: android, android-layout, recyclerview, constraint-layout

Tengo un `card_video.xml` (que es el elemento del que se rellena mi `RecyclerView`) el cual debería verse así según la vista de diseño de Android Studio, entiendo que no siempre se ve de esa manera debido a las propiedades de cada dispositivo, pero así debería verse para cada elemento:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cual tiene el siguiente codigo:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <TextView
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/textViewIndex"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_weight=".8"
            android:id="@+id/textViewNameCourse"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="Introduction"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonSee"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_eye_black_24dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Al llenar de datos el Recycler, termina viendose de esta manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí el codigo del Adapter

```
public class VideoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    ArrayList<Video> nVideoList;
    private int layout;
    private static OnItemClickListener listener;


    public VideoAdapter(ArrayList<Video> nVideoList, int layout, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.nVideoList = nVideoList;
        this.layout = layout;
        this.listener = listener;
    }


    @Override
    public VideoAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layout, parent, false);
        return new VideoAdapter.ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(VideoAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.index.setText((position+1)+"");
        holder.name.setText(nVideoList.get(position).getName());
        //events
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return nVideoList.size();
    }


    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        TextView name;
        TextView index;
        ImageView imageView;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNameCourse);
            index = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewIndex);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonSee);
            imageView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Llamas el método onItemClickListener() de la interfaz OnItemClickListener
            listener.onItemClickListener(view, getLayoutPosition());
        }
    }
    public interface OnItemClickListener{
        // Este método recibe como parámetro la vista del elemento seleccionado
        void onItemClickListener(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

Aquí el XML donde esta el RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.vycto.atomiccourses.VideoActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonBackToCourses"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".33"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white_24dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonHome"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".33"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_home_white" />

        <ImageButton
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".33"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_list_white" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardCornerRadius="15dp">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewCoverVideos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="127dp"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                android:src="@drawable/cover_default" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewNameCourse"
            android:text="Android"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="22sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewDescriptionCourse"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Ingrese aqui descripcion"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewCost1"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Cost: $0 (1 MONTH)"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewVideos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonBuy"
            android:text="Buy"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Necesito que se muestren todos los que cree como la primera imagen, gracias.

Comment: Has probado a cambiar el width del CardView a fill_parent??? no el del linearlayout, sino el del cardview, aunque... casi pondría el ancho de los 2 a fill_parent

Comment: Agrega el codigo de como estas inflando el CarView al RecycleView. Lo mas probable es que no estas asignadole el parent cuando lo inflas.

Comment: @Einer Listo, lo he subido.

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstafno voy a probar.

Comment: Estraño... Agrega la vista donde esta el `RecycleView` para poder mirar las propiedades de la misma.

Comment: He publicado el codigo XML donde esta el `RecycleView`.

Comment: @Parzival si vas a usa ConstraintLayout te aconsejo revisar primeramente como funciona, https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html agrego dos opciones para solucionar el problema que presentas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad tu archivo `card_video.xml` es correcto, los elementos que mostraría el `RecyclerView` tendrían este aspecto :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El "problema" real por el cual se muestran incorrectamente los elementos del  `RecyclerView` es que estas usando un [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html),  te aconsejo revisar la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html) para trabajar con este tipo de layout, ya que puede provocar comportamientos no esperados como el que indicas en tu pregunta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para solucionar este problema, en la definición del `RecyclerView` define `android:layout_height="match_parent"` en lugar de `android:layout_height="200dp`" :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Con esto provocaras que ademas de mostrar todos los elementos, estos se muestren correctamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Si es estrictamente necesario para tu aplicación definir 200dp como altura para tu `RecyclerView`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

La opción es cambiar el contenedor principal de un `ConstraintLayout` a un `LinearLayout` con orientación vertical,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.vycto.atomiccourses.VideoActivity">
...
...

</LinearLayout>
```

mediante este cambio tendrás el mismo resultado, mostrando correctamente los elementos dentro del `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Gracias por toda la información, funcionó.

Comment: Un placer @Parzival , no olvides leer lo relacionado a ContraintLayout para que no tengas dolores de cabeza como yo los tuve haha!, saludos!

Comment: Gracias por el consejo, para mañana te coloco mis 50 puntos.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que asignar `layout_width="0dp"` a las vistas, no `wrap_content`, para poder asignarles valores porcentuales:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="6">
    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/textViewIndex"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

       <!--Se cambio de wrap_content a 0dp-->
        android:layout_width="0dp"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:id="@+id/textViewNameCourse"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

       <!--Se cambio de wrap_content a 0dp-->
        android:layout_width="0dp"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Introduction"/>

    <ImageButton
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
        android:layout_width="33dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_eye_black_24dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Esto porque aunque no lo parezca, wrap_content es una unidad de medida que se calcula en runtime lo que causa que el sistema le asigne tamaño a las vistas y no valores porcentuales.

Recuerda que igual pasa si la orientacion del `LinearLayout` fuera vertical. En este caso seria el `layout_height="0dp"`.

**Actualizacion:**

Aunque no agregaste el codigo, tambien tienes que tener en cuenta que al momomento de inflar una vista, tienes que asignarle el `parent` para que la vista pueda calcular su tamaño cuando se utilize `match_parent`.

Verifica que no estas enviando null al momento de inflar:

```
 CardView cardView = (CardView)LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_video, null, false);
```

Tienes que enviarle el parent al inflate:

```
 CardView cardView = (CardView)LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_video, parent, false);
```

Comment: Hola, no me funcionó siguen deformandose al gusto del textView, creo.

Comment: Se ve igual como en la imagen que publicaste?

Comment: @Parzival mira la actualizacion que acabo de publicar.

Comment: si, siguen habiendo algunos que tienen otros tamaños, o incluso que aparecen pequeños y cuando hago scroll en el recyclerview toman bien el tamaño, pero en primera instancia no lo hacen.

Comment: Publica el codigo de tu adapter de como lo inflas para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 1):

yo sé una respuesta dado que se puede resolver de distintas maneras.
Y va relacionada con la propiedad `android:weightSum` la misma la definiste en 6 concretamente. Recomiendo la definas en 1 significará que equivale a un 100%
El linear layout esta en orientación horizontal por lo tanto la propiedad a la que vas a afectar en los hijos es `android:layout_width` por lo tanto la asignas siempre en cero y asignas porcentajes en `android:layout_weight`. Los porcentajes los asignas con .numero (atención: en el padre (LinearLayout) 1 = 100% por lo tanto asigno al primer hijo textview .1 = 10%, al segundo .8 = 80% y al tercero .1 = 10%) si no asignas el 100% lo que pasa es que los componentes se correrán a la izquierda.

Te ejemplifico:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewIndex"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewNameCourse"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight=".8"
            android:text="Introduction"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <ImageButton
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_..."/>


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Si quieres darle una mejor impresión agrega al cardView un padding. Además puede ser que la imagen no se vea bien, utiliza la propiedad ScaleType o bien optimizala para las diferentes densidades.

Espero te sea de ayuda

Saludos!